# Initializing a ListAdapter in Kivy file

Tags: python, kivy, listadapter

I'm new to Kivy and really like the separation between the code and the UI spec in the Kivy file.  I was hitting a roadblock in understanding how I might define a ListAdapter inside the Kivy file.  For example, here is a ListAdapter that is fully defined in the Python code:

```
class TestPop(Popup):

    a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestPop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        aAdapter = ListAdapter(data=self.a, cls=ListItemButton,
            args_converter = lambda row_index, x: {'text': x,'size_hint_y': None,
                'height': 50})
        aAdapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.click)
        myBox = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')
        myBox.add_widget(ListView(size_hint = (1,0.8), adapter = aAdapter))
        myBox.add_widget(Label(text = 'my pop', size_hint = (1,0.2)))
        self.add_widget(myBox)
        self.open

    def click(self, *args):
        print('click:{}'.format(args[0].selection[0].text))
```

Now, I can put part of the UI definition into the kivy file by changing the Python code to:

```
class TestPop2(Popup):

    a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.aAdapter = ListAdapter(data=self.a, cls=ListItemButton,
            args_converter = lambda row_index, x: {'text': x,'size_hint_y': None,
                'height': 50})
        self.aAdapter.bind(on_selection_change=self.click)
        super(TestPop2, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.open

    def click(self, *args):
        print('click:{0}'.format(args[0].selection[0].text))
```

and create a Kivy file:

```
<TestPop2>:
    title: 'type2 popup'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ListView:
            size_hint: (1,0.8)
            adapter: root.aAdapter
        Label:
            text: 'Test2 pop'
            size_hint: (1,0.2)
```

This will work.  But, I have problems moving the ListAdapter into the kivy file.  I tried this code:

```
class TestPop3(Popup):
    '''uses kv file but can't get on_selection_change to work
    '''
    a = ListProperty(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g'])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestPop3, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.open

    def click(self, *args):
        print('click:{0}'.format(args[0].selection[0].text))
```

with this kv file:

```
<TestPop3>:
    title: 'type3 popup'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ListView:
            size_hint: (1,0.8)
            adapter: ListAdapter(data=root.a,cls=ListItemButton,args_converter= lambda row_i, x:{'text':x,'size_hint_y':None,'height':50},on_selection_change= root.click)
        Label:
            text: 'Test3 pop'
            size_hint: (1,0.2)
```

but the on_selection_change doesn't work.  I am assuming there is something critical in when or how I bind the function to the event, and was trying to pass a reference back to the Python code through an ObjectProperty, but I can't figure it out.

Kivy ListAdapter documentation is located at http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.adapters.listadapter.html, but I couldn't find the solution there.  Some excellent code examples are at http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.listview.html, but I didn't see any that helped me with this question.

I'm also new to Python, so if there are comments about making my code more Pythonic or more accurate terminology in describing this issue, I'm all ears.